# Output is coming as undefined, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var code = prompt("enter a month number")
var month_name;
switch(code) {
case 1:
month_name = "January"
break;
case 4:
month_name = "April"
break;
case 8:
month_name = "August"
break;
default: "No match"
}
console.log(month_name)
```

Output is: undefined
Went through everything, nothing should be wrong here. I'm a high school student, so this may seem trivial but I have an exam tomorrow so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, changed  `default: "No match"` to `default: console.log("No match")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var code = prompt("enter a month number")
    code = parseInt(code);
    var month_name;
    switch(code) {
    case 1:
    month_name = "January"
    break;
    case 4:
    month_name = "April"
    break;
    case 8:
    month_name = "August"
    break;
    default: month_name = "No match"
    }
    console.log(month_name)
```